# How do I delete all lines but the last one using unix ed editor from a bash script

Tags: bash, text-editors

I have the following bash file called "file" (the real one does something useful):

```
ed db/seeds.rb <<EOF
1,$-1d
a
123
456
.
w
q
EOF
```

When I run "bash file" it doesn't delete any lines. If I use `1d` instead of `1,$-1d` it does delete the first line.

Why doesn't this work? I could easily do a workaround, but I'm curious why this doesn't work.

Comment: ed is meant to be run interactively.  Unless you're using `expect` or similar, the interactive portions can't be scripted in shell script.

Comment: When you have a portion of a script looking like: `ed file <<EOF` The script runs the command ("ed" in this case) such that the command thinks the following lines are inputed interactively. This continues until it encounters a line contained only the text following the `<<` (EOF in this case). I use this feature all the time.

Comment: `tail` is a dedicated tool for this task.

Comment: Again, this is just a simple example of what I'm doing in my real application. Tail would work, but it's not what my question is about. It's about ed.

Comment: By the way, @ernie, `diff -e` produces an `ed` script to convert _file1_ to _file2_. `ed` has supported non-interactive use since day 1, in the 1970s.

Comment: Yeah, I missed in the original that there was a redirect . . . I just saw a bunch of commands.  Mea culpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the shell is interpreting the `$` in the `1,$-1d` command. 
(Specifically, in my tests, it interprets `$-` as the collection of `set` flags.) 
The best way to fix this is to quote or escape the `EOF` string, as in

```
ed db/seeds.rb <<\EOF
```

or

```
ed db/seeds.rb <<"EOF"
```

Alternatively, you could escape (i.e., put a backslash in front of)
every `$` in your “here document”.

Comment: I ran into the same problem just now and it was in a context that was easier to understand. I had used solution of escaping the $ before (but obviously didn't remember), but I never knew the alternatives that you suggested. Less painful alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: Barmar makes a good point in [his comment](http://superuser.com/questions/800611/how-do-i-delete-all-lines-but-the-last-one-using-unix-ed-editor-from-a-bash-scri/800738?noredirect=1#comment1044864_800642): if you want to, you can use shell variables in your “here document”. In that case, you should ***not*** quote or escape the `EOF` string, but just escape the `$`s that you want handled literally (leaving the variable references, e.g., `$HOME`, alone).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I don't use shell variables very often. The dollar signs typically appear nowadays in angularjs code.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is simpler in this case. Pick one of:

```
sed -i -n '$p' file
sed -i '$!d' file
```

The error with your code is that the shell is expanding `$-` before passing the script to `ed`. This will work:

```
# quoting the heredoc word:
ed db/seeds.rb <<'EOF'
1,$-1d
w
q
EOF
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my real use, I add lines of text after I deleted what was there already.

Comment: @FredFinkle then append to the file.

Comment: If the real application needs to refer to variables in the here-doc, you could use `<<EOF` and escape the literal dollar signs with backslash.

Comment: sed doesn't edit in place, so it's a different beast.